# get max from a column and compare to each item of a column

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe such as:

```
id | value | date1       | date2
-------------------------------------
1  | 20    | 2015-09-01  | 2018-03-01 
1  | 30    | 2019-04-04  | 2015-03-02 
1  | 40    | 2014-01-01  | 2016-06-09 
2  | 15    | 2014-01-01  | 2013-06-01 
2  | 25    | 2019-07-18  | 2016-07-07
```

and want to return for each `id` the `sum(value)` where `date1<max(date2)` for that `id`. In the above example we will get:

```
id | sum_value 
-----------
1  | 60     
2  | 15
```

since for `id` 1 the `max(date2)` is `2018-03-01` and the first and third row fits the condition `date1<max(date2)` and therefore the value is sum of `20` and `40`.

I have tried the code below but we can't use `max` outside the `agg` function.

```
df.withColumn('sum_value',F.when(F.col('date1')<F.max(F.col('date2')), value).otherwise(0))
            .groupby(['id'])
```

Do you have any suggestions? The table is 2 billion rows so I am looking for other options than re-joining.

Comment: I think you would need a suppport table that contains the max `date2` value of each id, to then join it and apply the filter, I can't work it out in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Window` function. Direct translation of your requirements would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as _max, sum as _sum
from pyspark.sql import Window

df.withColumn("max_date2", _max("date2").over(Window.partitionBy("id")))\
    .where(col("date1") < col("max_date2"))\
    .groupBy("id")\
    .agg(_sum("value").alias("sum_value"))\
    .show()
#+---+---------+
#| id|sum_value|
#+---+---------+
#|  1|     60.0|
#|  2|     15.0|
#+---+---------+
```